# Cannot count dropped items

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to move items from one area to another using jQuery UI. When a box is moved from the left area and dropped in the yellow area I count remaining and show progress bar.

For some reason the first drag is counted but not the following -- why?

I tried to count using `length`:

```
$("#launchPad .card").length;
```

Comment: First thing I noticed are the `syntax error
[Break On This Error] <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> ` errors. Make sure there are no characters (even spaces) before your `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("#launchPad .card").length` is counting all `div.card` inside `td#launchPad` so the initial number is 5. But when you drag a `div.card` you only change the position of the element but is still inside of `#launchPad`, so your local variable `currentCount` is 5 too.

You would add a class to identify the dropped objects in your `drop` event. You can try with something like this:

```
$("#dropZone").bind( "drop", function(event, ui) {

    $(ui.draggable).addClass('dropped');
    var currentCount = $("#launchPad .card:not(.dropped)").length;
```

**EDIT:**

I mean you have the next DOM in your `#launchPad`:

```
<td id="launchPad" class="ui-droppable">&nbsp;
    <div id="CARD2674" class="card ui-draggable" style="position: relative; ">Task 2</div>
    <div id="CARD2677" class="card ui-draggable" style="position: relative; ">Task 5</div>
    <div id="CARD2675" class="card ui-draggable" style="position: relative; ">Task 3</div>
    <div id="CARD2673" class="card ui-draggable" style="position: relative; ">Task 1</div>
    <div id="CARD2676" class="card ui-draggable" style="position: relative; ">Task 4</div>
</td>
```

Then for jQuery your `div.card` are always inside `#launchPad` so `$("#launchPad .card").length` always returns 5.

I put a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p3YZx/7/).

Comment: I am so sorry. Yes, your code worked well. I added both lines but accidentally left the old count line. Removed it and it works great now. in fact I trimmed down the code and it still works great!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this code is the issue:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "uxowBCc",
        type: "POST",  
        data : "saveCard=33&idCard="+idCard+"&x="+x+"&y="+y,
        dataType: "script",
         success: function(data){
            eval( data);
           } 
        });
```

It is expecting JavaScript as a response but is getting the HTML structure of the page.

This is what is being stored in the `data` variable:

```
<!-- It seems like you have a couple lines of nothing up here that shouldn't be -->

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/testStyle.css">

<link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css" href="/jq/UI/css/blitzer/uimin.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/jq/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/jq/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>console.info("id: 299");console.info("2674    299    43    53");

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I fixed the spacing before <DOCTYPE> Thanks for letting me know. I believe I need to keep that .ajax function as it posts coordinates that are stored in my db. I didn't write the function but I'm sure that's what is if for. Maybe it needs to be re-written to correct whatever problems it has...

Answer (score 1):

It's because when the `#launchpad .card` item is dragged, it's only visibly in the other table cells and not physically (as far as the DOM is concerned) in the other table cells.  Notice line 227

```
var currentCount = $("#launchPad .card").length;
```

this will always be 5 because the nodes are never moved.  It works the first time, because you assume the transfer was successful and simply decrement this number giving you 4 or 20%.

A possible solution is to simply remove the node from #launchpad after a move and append it to another node outside of #launchpad or maybe adding a class to moved nodes and changing the above code to

```
var currentCount = $("#launchPad .card:not(.moved)").length;
```